# How to verify all collections are instanced in all entities in the context

Tags: c#, reflection, collections, entity-framework-6

I have a `DbContext` with multiple `DbSet<>` properties.
Some of those `DbSet<>` have `Icollection<>` objects  (navigation properties).

I want to write a unit test which checks if all those `ICollection<>` properties are instanced in my entities constructors.

Here is where I am this far:

```
// this.ctx is the instance of my DbContext
var allProps = this.ctx.GetType().GetProperties();
var allDbSets = allProps.Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>));
var allEntities = allDbSets.SelectMany(pi => pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments());

foreach (var entity in allEntities)
{
    // get collections of entity
    var genericProps = entity.GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType);
    var collections = genericProps.Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));

    if(collections.Any())
    {
        foreach (var coll in collections)
        {
            // coll is the PropertyInfo of a ICollection<> object.
        }
    }
}
```

From there I'm blocked.  I don't see how I can test that the collection is instanced.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often, I found the answer just after posting the question...

I just needed to instanciate the entity and get the value of the collection property to check if it's not null.

```
var allProps = this.ctx.GetType().GetProperties();
var allDbSets = allProps.Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>));
var allEntities = allDbSets.SelectMany(pi => pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments());

foreach (var entity in allEntities)
{
    // get collections of entity
    var genericProps = entity.GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType);
    var collections = genericProps.Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));

    if(collections.Any())
    {
        var ent = Activator.CreateInstance(entity);

        foreach (var coll in collections)
        {
            // coll is the PropertyInfo of a ICollection<> object.
            var val = coll.GetValue(ent);
            Assert.IsNotNull(val);
        }
    }
}
```